# Converting Class component to functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to convert React class component to functional component.

```
const remoteVideoref = useRef(null);

this.pc.ontrack = (e) => {
      this.remoteVideoref.current.srcObject = e.streams[0]
    }
```

Is this the correct way of doing it?

```
const remoteVideoref = useRef(null);

this.pc.ontrack = (e) => {
      remoteVideoref.current.srcObject = e.streams[0]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Assume this class component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    name: ''
  }

  alertName = () => {
    alert(this.state.name);
  };

  handleNameInput = e => {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>This is a Class Component</h3>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={this.handleNameInput}
          value={this.state.name}
          placeholder="Your Name"
        />
        <button onClick={this.alertName}>
          Alert
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When you types a name in the input field and clicks the Alert button, it pops up an alert with the name defined in state.

**You can convert this entire class into a functional React component using Hooks:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
    
    function App() {
      const [name, setName] = useState('John Doe');
    
      const alertName = () => {
        alert(name);
      };
    
      const handleNameInput = e => {
        setName(e.target.value);
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <h3>This is a Functional Component</h3>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={handleNameInput}
            value={name}
            placeholder="Your Name"
          />
          <button onClick={alertName}>
            Alert
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;
```

If this is what you mean, then I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

function component code for your code will be as following

```
const remoteVideoref = useRef(null);

const ontrack = (e) => {
  remoteVideoref.current.srcObject = e.streams[0]
}
```

and your can call ontrack function anywhere like `ontrack(event)`